# Recursive regular expression in Perl 6?

Tags: regex, raku

I've been trying to figure out how to do a recursive regular expression in Perl 6. For a toy example, a balanced parentheses matcher, which would match `((())())` inside `(((((())())`.

- [PCRE](https://regex101.com/r/otEKh5/1) example: `/\((?R)?\)/`
- [Onigmo](https://rubular.com/r/chy2TdjBeiIWM8) example: `(?<paren>\(\g<paren>*\))`

I thought this would do it:

```
my regex paren {
  '(' ~ ')' <paren>*
}
```

or the simpler

```
my regex paren {
  '(' <paren>* ')'
}
```

but that fails with

```
No such method 'paren' for invocant of type 'Match'
in regex paren at ...
```

Comment: See also [Parsing a possibly nested braced item using a grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47124405/2173773)

Comment: @HåkonHægland: Thanks, especially that [link](https://examples.perl6.org/categories/best-of-rosettacode/balanced-brackets.html) was a nice find. However, I was explicitly trying not to look at grammars since I want to find all matching spans, not parse a string from start, and I don't think grammars support that. That said, I am a noob at P6, so I am sure I'm missing something.

Comment: @HåkonHægland I mean I guess I can make a grammar that has `nonparen` as stuff I don't want, and an action class that will collect the `paren` matches... but that gets complicated fast... It's just very hard to believe P6 regular expressions dropped support for something Perl basically pioneered.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to make explicit that you're calling a `my`-scoped regex:

```
my regex paren {
    '(' ~ ')' <&paren>*
}
```

Notice the `&` that has been added. With that:

```
say "(()())" ~~ /^<&paren>$/    # ｢(()())｣
say "(()()" ~~ /^<&paren>$/     # Nil
```

While it's true that you can sometimes get away without explicitly writing the `&`, and indeed could when using it:

```
say "(()())" ~~ /^<paren>$/    # ｢(()())｣
say "(()()" ~~ /^<paren>$/     # Nil
```

This only works because the compiler spots there is a regex defined in the lexical scope with the name `paren` so compiles the `<paren>` syntax into that. With the recursive case, the declaration isn't installed until after the regex is parsed, so one needs to be explicit.

Comment: Perfect, that was the missing piece. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `~~` in the meta-syntax to make a recursive callback into the current pattern or just a part of it. For example, you can match balanced parenthesis with the simple regex:

```
say "(()())" ~~ /'(' <~~>* ')'/;    # ｢(()())｣
say "(()()"  ~~ /'(' <~~>* ')'/;    # ｢()｣
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVJBSUNDU0NTU0mhrk5BX11DXcGmrs5OS0FdU13fWgEIlBXe710EUfN@72IuhBYlBfxaQMr//wcA)

Unfortunately, matching via a captured subrule (like `~~0`) is not yet implemented.