# Perl6 Parse File

Tags: regex, grammar, raku

As practice, I'm trying to parse some standard text that is an output of a shell command.

```
  pool: thisPool
 state: ONLINE
status: Some supported features are not enabled on the pool. The pool can
    still be used, but some features are unavailable.
action: Enable all features using 'zpool upgrade'. Once this is done,
    the pool may no longer be accessible by software that does not support
    the features. See zpool-features(5) for details.
  scan: none requested
config:

    NAME                                                STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    homePool                                            ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-0                                          ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD5000AZLX-00CL5A0_WD-WCC3F7NUE93C      ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD5000AZLX-00CL5A0_WD-WCC3F7RE2A4F      ONLINE       0     0     0
    cache
      ata-KINGSTON_SV300S37A60G_50026B7261025D7E-part3  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

I want to use a Perl6 grammar and I want to capture each of the fields in a separate token or regex. So, I made the following grammar:

```
grammar zpool {
        regex TOP { \s+ [ <keyword> <collection> ]+ }
        token keyword { "pool: " | "state: " | "status: " | "action: " | "scan: " | "config: " | "errors: " }
        regex collection { [<:!keyword>]*  }
}
```

My idea is that the regex finds a keyword, then begins collecting all the data until the next keyword. However, each time, I just get "pool: " -> all the remaining text.

```
 keyword => ｢pool: ｣
 collection => ｢homePool
 state: ONLINE
status: Some supported features are not enabled on the pool. The pool can
    still be used, but some features are unavailable.
action: Enable all features using 'zpool upgrade'. Once this is done,
    the pool may no longer be accessible by software that does not support
    the features. See zpool-features(5) for details.
  scan: none requested
config:

    NAME                                                STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    homePool                                            ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-0                                          ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD5000AZLX-00CL5A0_WD-WCC3F7NUE93C      ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD5000AZLX-00CL5A0_WD-WCC3F7RE2A4F      ONLINE       0     0     0
    cache
      ata-KINGSTON_SV300S37A60G_50026B7261025D7E-part3  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
｣
```

I don't know how to get it to stop eating the characters when it finds a keyword and then treat that as another keyword.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Problem 1**

You've written `<:!keyword>` instead of `<!keyword>`. That's not what you want. You need to delete the `:`.

The `<:foo>` syntax in a P6 regex [matches a single character with the specified Unicode property](https://docs.perl6.org/syntax/%3C:property%3E), in this case the property `:foo` which in turn means `:foo(True)`.

And `<:!keyword>` matches a single character with the Unicode property `:keyword(False)`.

But there is no Unicode property `:keyword`.

So the negative assertion will always be true and will always match a single character of input each time.

So the pattern just munches its way thru the rest of the text, as you know.

**Problem 2**

Once you fix problem 1, a second problem arises.

`<:!keyword>` matches a single character with the Unicode property `:keyword(False)`. It automatically munches *some* input (a single character) each time it matches.

In contrast, `<!keyword>` does not consume any input if it matches. *You have to make sure the pattern that uses it munches input.*

---

After fixing those two problems you'll get the sort of output you expected. (The next problem you'll see is that the `config` keyword doesn't work because the `:` in `config:` in your input file example isn't followed by a space.)

---

So, with a few clean ups:

```
my @keywords = <pool state status action scan config errors> ;

say grammar zpool {
    token TOP        { \s+ [ <keyword> <collection> ]* }
    token keyword    { @keywords ': ' }
    token collection { [ <!keyword> . ]* }
}
```

I've switched all the patterns to `token` declarations. In general, always use `token` unless you *know* you need something else. (`regex` enables backtracking. That can dramatically slow things down if you're not careful. `rule` makes spaces *in the rule* significant.)

I've extracted the keywords into an array. `@keywords` means `@keywords[0] | @keywords[1] | ...`.

I've added a `.` after `<!keyword>` in the last pattern (to consume a character's worth of input, to avoid the infinite loop that would otherwise occur given that `<!foo>` does not consume any input).

In case you haven't seen them, note that the [available grammar debugging options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19640657/1077672) are your friend.

Hth

Answer (score 3):

As much as I love a good grammar now and then, this is much easier to solve with a call to [split](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/split.html):

```
my $input = q:to/EOF/;
  pool: thisPool
 state: ONLINE
status: Some supported features are not enabled on the pool. The pool can
    still be used, but some features are unavailable.
action: Enable all features using 'zpool upgrade'. Once this is done,
    the pool may no longer be accessible by software that does not support
    the features. See zpool-features(5) for details.
  scan: none requested
config:

    NAME                                                STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    homePool                                            ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-0                                          ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD5000AZLX-00CL5A0_WD-WCC3F7NUE93C      ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD5000AZLX-00CL5A0_WD-WCC3F7RE2A4F      ONLINE       0     0     0
    cache
      ata-KINGSTON_SV300S37A60G_50026B7261025D7E-part3  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
EOF

my @delimiter = <pool state status action scan config errors>;
my %fields;
for $input.split( / ^^ \h* (@delimiter) ':' \h*/, :v)[1..*] -> $key, $value {
    %fields{ $key[0] } = $value.trim;
}

say %fields.perl;
```

This works by splitting on known keys, discarding the first element (since we know the input starts with a key, not a value), and then iterating keys and values in lockstep.

Now since you asked for a grammar, we can easily turn the `split` call to a pure regex by replacing each value with `.+?` (any string, but as short as possible).

And now let's give it some more structure:

```
my @delimiter = <pool state status action scan config errors>;
grammar ZPool {
    regex key      { @delimiter             }
    regex keychunk { ^^ \h* <key> ':'       }
    regex value    { .*?                    }
    regex chunks   { <keychunk> \h* <value> }
    regex TOP      { <chunks>+              }
}
```

We could do the hard work of extracting the result from the nested match tree, or instead cheat with a stateful action object:

```
class ZPool::Actions {
    has $!last-key;
    has %.contents;
    method key($m)   { $!last-key = $m.Str                }
    method value($m) { %!contents{ $!last-key } = $m.trim }
}
```

And then use it:

```
my $actions = ZPool::Actions.new;
ZPool.parse($input, :$actions);
say $actions.contents.perl;
```

`key` and `keychunk` don't need to backtrack, so you can change them from `regex` to `token`.

Of course, using `.+?` and backtracking could be considered cheating, so you can use the trick that raiph mentioned with a negative look-ahead inside the `value` regex.